# How do I use an array formula to get column data from a sheet based a checkbox?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have 3 sheets.

The first one `Master` contains my source data.

In the other two sheets I'm trying to get columns A-C from the source data `Master!A:C` based on the state of the checkboxes in columns D or E:

- `Sheet2` uses the checkboxes in `Master!D:D`
- `Sheet3` uses the checkboxes in `Master!E:E`

## Example Tables

###### Master (source data)

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Neither | Neither | Neither | ◻ | ◻ |
| **2** | Both | Both | Both | ▣ | ▣ |
| **3** | Sheet2 | Sheet2 | Sheet2 | ▣ | ◻ |
| **4** | Sheet3 | Sheet3 | Sheet3 | ◻ | ▣ |

###### Sheet2

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Both <sup>***** `Master!A2`</sup> | Both <sup>***** `Master!B2`</sup> | Both <sup>***** `Master!C2`</sup> |
| **2** | Sheet2 <sup>***** `Master!A3`</sup> | Sheet2 <sup>***** `Master!B3`</sup> | Sheet2 <sup>***** `Master!C3`</sup> |

###### Sheet3

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Both <sup>***** `Master!A2`</sup> | Both <sup>***** `Master!B2`</sup> | Both <sup>***** `Master!C2`</sup> |
| **2** | Sheet3 <sup>***** `Master!A4`</sup> | Sheet3 <sup>***** `Master!B4`</sup> | Sheet3 <sup>***** `Master!C4`</sup> |

How can I use an array formula the return data from columns A-C in `Master` based on a checkbox in either column D or E?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Put this formula in cell `A2` on `Sheet2`:

```
=filter(Master!A2:C, Master!D2:D)
```

...and this formula in cell `A2` on `Sheet3`:

```
=filter(Master!A2:C, Master!E2:E)
```